# Movie about a student-teacher relationship that goes horribly wrong

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw (*) a movie on an airplane flight that looked like it involved a student seducing or otherwise getting involved with a teacher. Eventually while the teacher was out of his house, the student kidnapped his wife, locked her in the trunk of a car, and bribed a junkyard's manager to crush the car without proper paperwork. Then she went back to the teacher's house and sent an email using their computer, from the wife to the teacher saying she was leaving because of the affair.

The actors were white, but obviously I don't know what language they were speaking since I couldn't hear it. I watched it more than one and less than 6 years ago.

What is this movie?

(*) but did not hear because I was too cheap to buy the proprietary headphones.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points.  The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you. I'm assuming from your question that you saw this on a flight? Can you clarify?

Comment: I've added the details though I don't know how helpful they will be.

Comment: Do you remember which airline you were on? Where were you traveling? If it's an American company, the film was likely a Hollywood film... do you remember if it was on the main cabin screen or something you watched on an individual seat back screen? The former would imply that it's a comedy/action film, the latter can be a broader variety.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the movie is [*Damaged*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4238476/) (2014)

Reading a review brought back a few details I had forgotten:

- The student lives across the street from the teacher.
- She lets him borrow her car and gives him a watch.
- She kills the wife with a hammer, but not in the teacher's house; rather the wife breaks into the student's house.

I wasn't able to find anything about the car-crushomatic. But it's an obscure, terrible, made-for-tv, Lifetime movie, so details/plot summaries are scant.

Comment: Interesting. I would not have expected a film of such low caliber to appear on an airline. Let us know for sure if you happen to find it and watch it.

Comment: I'm guessing it was a JetBlue flight; they show TV channels on their flights.

Comment: Definitely *Damaged*. The girl bribes a junkyard owner to crush the wife's car and sends the husband a fake e-mail from her saying that she's leaving him.

Comment: @stannius Upvote for recognizing such an obscure flick!

Comment: Thanks to the site regulars for letting me use your site for some duck debugging!

Comment: @SeanDuggan what brings you to make such a comment and propose an edit a year later?

Comment: I ran into the question off of the Related list to the right. :) And I figured, hey, why not?